# How to use templates in emails in Play framework 2.0?

Tags: email, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm using this [module](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer) to send mail in my playframework application and I was wondering if its possible to use some template in the mail like the ones used in the Play 1.2.4 [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/emails).

I'm using Play 2.0.3

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact it is quite simple. Here is a sample of code.

```
val mail = use[MailerPlugin].email  

def sendEmail() = {
    mail.setSubject("Your subject")
    mail.addRecipient("Somename <example@example.com>")
    mail.addFrom("Someone <noreply@example.com>")
    mail.send(
        views.txt.helpers.mail.myTemplate().toString, 
        views.html.helpers.mail.myTemplate().toString
    )
}
```